# Is there any keyboard shortcut to switch my mouse cursor from one desktop to another?

Tags: macos, keyboard, display, shortcut

I have connected my macBookPro multiples screens from left to right, 1,2,3,4,5...

Is there any keyboard shortcut to just move my cursor from monitor 1 to monitor 5 **without me needing to drag my mouse all the way?**

Or possibly a keyboard shortcut that would also move my cursor to the new focused(I mean if I switch apps using Cmmd + Tab) app

Answer (score 2):

There's no shortcut to my knowledge but if you are willing to get your hands a little dirty you can easily achieve this with a combination of 3rd party software, here is how I'd go about it:

- Download and install [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html).
- Download and install [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com).
- Add KM Macro based on keys combination (to switch from one screen to another, one Macro for each display).
- Finally for each macro add the Shell action with MouseTools -x xValue -y yValue (which are the coordinate on the display where you want the mouse to land).

Comment: It's really easy, you can get the mouse position by running ```./MouseTool -location``` so do that when the mouse is at the centre of your display, repeat on the other one and use these values in the macros.